# Expected count of correct assignments

Tags: probability, expectation

There are $40$ letters and $40$ envelopes with addresses. The letters are put in envelopes at random. What is the expected number of letters in their corresponding (correct) envelopes ?

One envelope can hold only one letter.

I start with $E(X_i)=1\cdot\dfrac{1}{40}+0\cdot\dfrac{39}{40}=\dfrac{1}{40}$.

$X_i$ being the $i^{th}$ letter placed correctly or not ($1$, if correctly placed and $0$, if not). I need to calculate the expected count of letters assigned correctly.

Then add up all $\implies$ $E(X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_{40})=\underbrace{\dfrac{1}{40}+\dfrac{1}{40}+\ldots+\dfrac{1}{40}}_{40\text{ times}}=1$

Now my doubt is that if I put $39$ letters correctly, the $40^{th}$ one will be automatically assigned correctly . So should I add only $39$ times ?

Any other mistakes I may be doing here ? Please advise.

Comment: If an envelope is "filled" every time a letter is put in, and can no longer be used, then the $X_i$ are not at all independent. Whether this is the case is not really clear from your writing.

Comment: Your $40$ is good. You should explain what the $X_i$ are.

Comment: You’re fine. You’re observation is that the events $X_i$ are not independent, but that doesn’t matter. The linearity of expectation holds regardless of independence.

Comment: @Ian When it comes to expected value, this is irrelevant. $1/40$th of the permutations will have the letter in the correct place, and we can add them by linearity.

Comment: @MattSamuel Ah right, good catch.

Comment: I edited my question about the $X_i$ ... please check

Comment: Your answer is correct.  You can check this by hand on a simple case, say with only 3 or 4 envelopes: list all $3!$ or $4!$ possible assignments of letters to envelopes, count up the total number of correct assignments, and compute the average.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of envelopes that go to the correct place is
$$X_1+\cdots+X_{40}$$
The expected value is
$$E[X_1+\cdots+X_{40}]=1$$
as you have computed. The fact that the $X_i$ depend on each other is irrelevant as expectation is linear.